# How to add code to Portable Executable?

Tags: pe, patching

I have a PE which I'd like to edit. I know I can create patches in OllyDbg and similar tools, but they all have one thing in common: I have to overwrite some present code in file. I wonder if it is possible to somehow enlarge the executable, put the code in the appended part, and then just change a few instructions in original part to `jmp` to the new part? I searched over the Internet, but I haven't found an obvious solution (well, some propose writing code in NOP sections, but my code i longer than the longest of them).

Note that the PE is 64-bit, so the solution must work for this architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a new section to your PE file.

High-level instructions at [Adding sections to PE Files](http://www.woodmann.com/fravia/covert1.htm) and low-level instructions at [Inject your code to a Portable Executable file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12532/Inject-your-code-to-a-Portable-Executable-file).

Comment: Also, related post on this site (though not a duplicate) - [Add Section to pe file function error](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/add-section-to-pe-file-function-error)

Comment: The thing I eventually went by was adding a new section in PELord at the very end and put my code there.